# Crazy Stuff with Inkscape: copy/paste and PDF 

Tags: pdf, inkscape

OK, so I was creating a PDF with Inkscape using images from the web. I copied them and pasted them all in Inkscape, nothing strange, but then every time I copied a new image to the Inkscape workspace somehow the images that were already there got replaced with the image I just copied. I don't know if it's a feature of Inkscape or something like that, or could it be Ubuntu.

Well, I certainly don't know what it is but it's rather annoying.

Also this affects the PDF files that were already created. Say I have a PDF with an image of a dog, and I click copy and choose the image of a cat, the PDF file gets edited, even when it's not in use.

Comment: can you attach some screenshots so we can better understand what is happening?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Do you copy & paste the images via a clipboard manager or do you save the files first and then import them in Inkscape?

Comment: how do i attach the screenshoots here?,

Im using Google´s Chrome browser ,i guess im using the default maverick cipboard manager as i haven´t customized ubuntu that much.

Comment: I'm not at all a fan of ManU (sorry, I'm always with Kloppo's teams) -- but man am I a fanboy of what you created with Nitrux!!!! -- Congrats, and all kudos to you. Nitrux is a big achievement! Thank you for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best guess: you are only linking to the images within the PDF file and everytime you copy a new image, the old one gets replaced (maybe caused by a clipboard manager).

There are two ways to include a raster image in Inkscape: either link to it (then you need the PDF and the image file to see the whole document) or embed it (then the PDF will also contain the image's data).

I'd save whatever image you want to disk, then import it in Inkscape (File > Import...):

[image]

and select "embed" in above dialog.

Comment: I'm sorry, my "best guess" wasn't good enough. What I've described only seems to work with SVG files, not with PDF files. There should be no way to change images in an already created PDF file by changing files outside of the PDF file. :-/